# Alternatives to Editing accels.scm File in Thunar?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce, thunar, thunar-custom-actions

Since GTK3+ removed editable accelerators, everything I've read online suggests I'm stuck having to edit the `~/.config/Thunar/accels.scm` file if I want to assign keyboard shortcuts to actions or folders in Thunar. Is there another option? For instance, say I wanted to assign a keyboard shortcut to open a folder in my current Thunar window. Could I do this with a custom action, or maybe a bash script?

Answer (score 2):

To assign a shortcut key, you indeed are stuck for the moment to editing the `~/.config/Thunar/accels.scm` file. Indeed, the GTK2 mechanism to assign a shortcut key on the fly has disappeared in GTK3, leaving you with no other option than to edit the file, until someone develops a graphical user interface to assign shortcut keys to Thunar menu items, including custom actions that you can create yourself.

Comment: The other actions aren't too bad, but the keys to open folders are a pain because the folder paths are all hashed values in the accels.scm file. Is there an easier way to figure out which hashed value corresponds to which folder other than trial and error?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but you could open a question for that.